# How to read and write Esri FileGeodatabase (FileGDB) in Linux by Java language？

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, java, write

I need to read and write Esri FileGDB in a Linux system (Centos).I have installed GDAL and compiled the Java package.Then, I tried to use FileGDB API to accomplish the task, but it does not support Java language.

Comment: Can you include your Java code and error message in your posting?

Comment: There exist JNI wrappers for the FGDB C++ library.

Comment: Can you tell me where to download or how to install JNI wrappers for the FGDB C++ library？Tanks.

Comment: Note that by default GDAL uses the OpenFileGDB driver, which is read-only.  You need to use the ESRI FileGDB driver for write access and this requires the ESRI fGDB API SDK to be installed.  See:  https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html  (I've no idea if this is accessible in Java or not.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use GDAL via JNI. You can see the available Java artifacts here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.gdal/gdal The Javadoc is located here: https://gdal.org/java/index.html

There is also https://github.com/OpenSextant/giscore native Java implementation but it seems outdated.